# Regexp to delete white space between </a> and another <a>

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm pretty bad in regexp and I would really appreciate your advice.
I have string in JavaScript containing two links with the white space in between.
So basically every time this occurs `</a> <a` to change it into `</a><a`.

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Why would you need a regex for that? Seems a simple string replace would do.

Comment: @Tim - replace in JavaScript only replaces the first occurrence :)

Comment: @Jeffrey: Bah, humbug! You should be flagged for that.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
var newstring = mystring.replace(/<\/a>\s+<a/g, "</a><a");
```

Comment: you need to escape your slash in the regex

Answer (score 0):

```
var output = input.replace(/<\/a>\s+<a/g,"</a><a")
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be something like this:
find `/<\/a>[\s\r\n]+<a/g`
replace `"</a><a"`

Comment: `\r` and `\n` are both included in `\s`. i.e. `[\s\r\n] === \s`

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
string = string.replace("</a> <a","</a><a")
```

or

```
string = string.replace(/<\/a>\s+<a/g,"</a><a")
```

to replace also multiple spaces, tabs etc.

Comment: What if there are two spaces, three, a tab? This is wher ea regex really helps.

Comment: Well, yes, than you could just do `string.replace(/<\/a>\s+<a/g,"</a><a")
` of course.

Comment: this will also only replace the first instance... you need a regex to replace all instances.

Comment: @downvoter: it might be helpful to know the reason for a downvote